# Route is not defined, laravel breeze inertia react SSR

Tags: reactjs, laravel, laravel-8, inertiajs, laravel-breeze

I am trying to use [SSR inertiajs](https://inertiajs.com/server-side-rendering) with react, in laravel.

Version details:

Php: 8.1.2
Laravel: 8.82.0
Breeze: 1.7.1
Inertiajs: 0.11.0
Npm: 8.1.2

/resources/js/ssr.js

```
createServer((page) => createInertiaApp({
  page,
  render: ReactDOMServer.renderToString,
  resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
  setup: ({ App, props }) => <App {...props} />,
}))
```

/webpack.ssr.mix.js

```
mix
  .options({ manifest: false })
  .js('resources/js/ssr.js', 'public/js')
  .react()
  .alias({ '@': path.resolve('resources/js') })
  .webpackConfig({
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
  })
```

/resources/views/app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        ...
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
        @routes
        <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
        @inertiaHead
    </head>
    <body class="font-sans antialiased">
        @inertia

        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: route is not defined
at Welcome (/public/js/ssr.js:1413:19)
```

Comment: Please add they way you defined `route`

Comment: If someone has same problem please check https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/issues/1083

Comment: Hello Parth, First of all, you can upgrade from webpack to vite and if you face an issue, then the "bee bee" solution is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get ziggy-js

```
npm install ziggy-js
```

Then run

```
php artisan ziggy:generate
```

Which should create a ziggy.js file in the resources/js directory. After modify your ssr.js to

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react'
import createServer from '@inertiajs/server'
import route from "ziggy-js";
import { Ziggy } from '@/ziggy'


createServer((page) => createInertiaApp({
    page,
    render: ReactDOMServer.renderToString,
    resolve: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`),
    setup: ({ App, props }) => {

        // Set global function route
        global.route = (name, params, absolute, config = Ziggy) => route(name, params, absolute, config);

        return <App {...props} />
    },
}))
```

[Solution by JefteCaro](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/issues/1083#issuecomment-1038850168)

[More solutions in case you'd like to read more](https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia/issues/1083)

Comment: Hello bee bee, This solution worked for me in the latest laravel 10 and inertia js version. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One question is that, Why such important information is not updated on the official documentation. It is mandatory to do this way, otherwise we are getting this above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? It was in the Routing - Inertia.

`app.config.globalProperties.$route = route`

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

with

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/ssr.js') }}" defer></script>
```

in /resources/views/app.blade.php